# Play Scala - groupBy remove repetitive values

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-collections

I apply `groupBy` function to my List collection, however I want to remove the repetitive values in the value part of the Map. Here is the initial List collection:

```
PO_ID       PRODUCT_ID      RETURN_QTY
1           1               10
1           1               20
1           2               30
1           2               10
```

When I apply groupBy to that List, it will produce something like this:

```
(1, 1) -> (1, 1, 10),(1, 1, 20)
(1, 2) -> (1, 2, 30),(1, 2, 10)
```

What I really want is something like this:

```
(1, 1) -> (10),(20)
(1, 2) -> (30),(10)
```

So, is there anyway to remove the repetitive part in the `Map`'s values `[(1,1),(1,2)]` ?
Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For

```
val a = Seq( (1,1,10), (1,1,20), (1,2,30), (1,2,10) )
```

consider

```
a.groupBy( v => (v._1,v._2) ).mapValues( _.map (_._3) )
```

which delivers

```
Map((1,1) -> List(10, 20), (1,2) -> List(30, 10))
```

Note that `mapValues` operates over a `List[List]` of triplets obtained from `groupBy`, whereas in `map` we extract the third element of each triplet.

Comment: Footnote mapValues is a view.

Answer (score 1):

Is it easier to pull the tuple apart first?

```
scala> val ts = Seq( (1,1,10), (1,1,20), (1,2,30), (1,2,10) )
ts: Seq[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,1,10), (1,1,20), (1,2,30), (1,2,10))

scala> ts map { case (a,b,c) => (a,b) -> c }
res0: Seq[((Int, Int), Int)] = List(((1,1),10), ((1,1),20), ((1,2),30), ((1,2),10))

scala> ((Map.empty[(Int, Int), List[Int]] withDefaultValue List.empty[Int]) /: res0) { case (m, (k,v)) => m + ((k, m(k) :+ v)) }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Int, Int),List[Int]] = Map((1,1) -> List(10, 20), (1,2) -> List(30, 10))
```

Guess not.